How to find multiple entries with multiple minimum values in a multidimensional PHP Array
I'm working on an online leaderboard, and basically I have a multidimensional array of completion times for an activity that looks something like this
array(4) { 
    [0]=> array(3) { 
        ["name"]=> "John Doe" 
        ["time_minutes"]=> 34 
        ["time_seconds"]=> 12
    } 
    [1]=> array(3) { 
        ["name"]=> "Jane Doe" 
        ["time_minutes"]=> 24 
        ["time_seconds"]=> 32
    } 
    [2]=> array(3) { 
        ["name"]=> "John Doe2" 
        ["time_minutes"]=> 14 
        ["time_seconds"]=> 52
    } 
    [3]=> array(3) { 
        ["name"]=> "Jane Doe2" 
        ["time_minutes"]=> 54 
        ["time_seconds"]=> 55
    } 
}


What I need is to get the array entries for the top 3 quickest times into a new array called $top_3. Or if I can just mutate the existing array so it only contains the 3 entries with the quickest times, that will also work.
I've tried to get the total time by running a for each loop and adding another key called 'total_time' which is 'time_minutes' * 60 + 'time_seconds' and trying to find the min value using that, but it's not adding this key to the original array (presumably since it's creating a copy instead of mutating the original).
Can someone please help me figure this out? Ideally I'd like to do this with no more than one loop because  there will be many entries and also many more keys that I've trimmed for brevity, and I'd like to keep the loading speed as quick as possible.
Thank you!

Sort the array by times in ascending order first (https://stackoverflow.com/q/17364127/1427878 should provide enough info, on how to achieve that), and then pick the first three elements.

I've tried to get the total time by running a for each loop perhaps showing your code will help others fix it.

Please show the code where you tried, including the data it ran on, i.e. a [mcve].

This is how I would do this,

Sort the array by the key ["time_minutes"] and ["time_seconds"].

usort($yourArray, function($a, $b) {

    $minuteComparison = $a['time_minutes'] <=> $b['time_minutes'];
    
    if ($minuteComparison === 0) {
        return $a['time_seconds'] <=> $b['time_seconds'];
    }

    return $minuteComparison;
});


Extract the top three items.

$topThreeQuickest = array_slice($yourArray, 0, 3);

I hope that solves the problem.

"Because checking the total time would be enough to find who was the quickest." But using only minutes is not the complete time ? the usort should also use seconds
